# Algebraic substructure and restriction of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

I am reading the follow pdf:

http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra2012.pdf

in particular at pg 28 of pdf, and I think that, let $(A;f)$ an algebric structure and $B \subseteq A $ and $B \neq \emptyset $,$ B$ is an algebraic substructure of $(A;f)$ if $(B;f_{|B})$ is an algebric structure and $f_{|B}$ is restriction function on $B$. It is correct?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, basically correct.

An algebraic structure may have *more* operations (e.g. ring).

The main thing for $B$ being subalgebra of $A$ is, that, *each* operation $f:A^n\to A$ *stays within* $B$ when applied to elements of $B$ (also said as "$B$ is closed under the operation $f$"), that is:
$f|_{B^n}:B^n\to A$
factors through $B$: $f(b_1,..,b_n)\in B$ for all $b_i\in B$.

In notation the restriction to $B^n$ of an $n$-ary operation $f$ is frequently written briefly $f|_B$, i.e. technically $f|_B$ can denote the restriction of $f$ to $B^n\subseteq A^n$.

Comment: but can I use this definition: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Restriction_of_Mapping#Definition?? In this case I have the restriction of $f$ to $(B \times B) \times B$, or in simbol $f{\restriction_{(B \times B) \times B}}$, with $f(B) \subseteq B$ or in other words $B$ has the property of closure under $f$... Is correct?? Thanks in advance!!